# C++ Socket Part-2 A (Utilities)

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

This is the code I use to dynamically build error messages.

### Utility.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_SOCKET_UTILITY_H
#define THORSANVIL_SOCKET_UTILITY_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace Socket
    {

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
print(std::ostream&, std::tuple<Tp...> const&)
{ }

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
print(std::ostream& s, std::tuple<Tp...> const& t)
{
    s << std::get<I>(t);
    print<I + 1, Tp...>(s, t);
}

template<typename... Args>
std::string buildStringFromParts(Args const&... args)
{
    std::stringstream msg;
    print(msg, std::make_tuple(args...));
    return msg.str();
}

template<typename... Args>
std::string buildErrorMessage(Args const&... args)
{
    return buildStringFromParts(args...);
}

    }
}

#endif
```

The code works for all types that can be streamed. Including io manipulators.

```
std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);

buildStringFromParts("Date: ", std::put_time(&tm, "%c %Z"), "\r\n");
```

This generates the string:

```
Date: Sun Jun  5 01:55:19 2016 PDT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only got a minor amount of suggestions to offer. Your code already does what it needs to do the proper way.

#### Missing headers

Consider including the specific header of the types you use instead of depending on other headers including them.

- Requires `<cstddef>` for `std::size_t`.
- Requires `<type_traits>` for `std::enable_if<>`
- Requires `<tuple>` for `std::tuple<>` and `std::get<>`. This one  is actually needed, otherwise you get an undefined reference to `std::get<>`.

#### Printing

Consider...

- Changing your condition to `I == sizeof...( Tp ) - 1` instead of `I == sizeof...( Tp )`. Will the compiler optimize away the last extra empty function call? Probably, but there's no reason to have it to begin with.
- Using the `_t` post-fix type traits for conciseness: `std::enable_if_t<>` over `typename std::enable_if<>::type`.
- The default `type` alias of `std::enable_if<>` is already `void`, there's no need to explicitly write it.

By applying those suggestions, we go from this:

```
template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
print(std::ostream&, std::tuple<Tp...> const&)
{ }

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
print(std::ostream& s, std::tuple<Tp...> const& t)
{
    s << std::get<I>(t);
    print<I + 1, Tp...>(s, t);
}
```

To this:

```
template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline std::enable_if_t<I == sizeof...( Tp ) - 1>
print( std::ostream& s, std::tuple<Tp...> const& t )
{
    s << std::get<I>( t );
}

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline std::enable_if_t<I < sizeof...( Tp ) - 1>
print( std::ostream& s, std::tuple<Tp...> const& t )
{
    s << std::get<I>( t );
    print<I + 1, Tp...>( s, t );
}
```

- Using the array pack-expansion trick to avoid recursion, the use of `std::tuple<>` and indexing.

By using that trick, the `print()` function can be simplified into:

```
template <class OutputStream, class... Args>
void print( OutputStream& os, Args&&... args )
{
    using expander = int[];
    expander{ ( (void) ( os << std::forward<Args>( args ) ), 0 )... };
}
```

You can apply the same trick to the `buildStringFromParts()` function. This will allow you to separate printing from building the string.

To compensate for some standard warning flags that most people have turned on by default (`-Werror -Wunused-value`) we need to force a use of the temporary. So extract the first element as a return value:

```
template<typename... Args>
int print(std::ostream& s, Args&... args)
{
    using Expander = int[];
    return Expander{ 0, ((s << std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...}[0];
}
```

Comment: (apologies for resurrecting an old answer). I'm trying to understand the advantages of the pack-expansion trick. My assumption is that it (a) increases brevity, and (b) prevents potential issues arising from recursion. Are there any other advantages/disadvantages, I assume the code after the template code generation is essentially the same

Comment: @cloakedlearning It ensures the correct ordering of statements as well. It performs just as well as an iterative version up to a certain large number of parameters (over 2000 I believe), so this is a non-issue.